# How to get sub string in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have string `http://mycloud.net/4d4bf89da2e38.jpg`

I want `4d4bf89da2e38.jpg`

How can i get this with php function or regexp.

Please Suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = pathinfo('http://mycloud.net/4d4bf89da2e38.jpg', PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `basename()` would probably be better in this case. But to answer your question title, you would use `substr()` to get a substring from a piece of text.

```
basename('http://mycloud.net/4d4bf89da2e38.jpg'); // returns 4d4bf89da2e38.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[^/]*$
```

will give you everything after the last slash.

In PHP:

```
if (preg_match('%[^/]*$%', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

But isn't there a library available to deal with file paths?

Answer (score 1):

Use basename() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php.
It is probably faster then regexp and it would be cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those functions, you only need to split the string.

$cadena='http://mycloud.net/4d4bf89da2e38.jpg';

$vec=explode("/",$cadena);

$name=array_pop($vec);

and you have the value in the variable $name

Answer (score 0):

Or you put sjmg answer in one line ;)

```
$name = array_pop(explode('/','http://mycloud.net/4d4bf89da2e38.jpg'));
```